# Adjective meaning 'interesting, but not relevant'

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for a word to describe a podcast I was listening to. The podcast was *interesting*, but contents weren't relevant to my life or objectives, it was just an interesting story that you might recount later at a dinner party, but not something that you would ponder at night time. The second part of the podcast *was* relevant, and I'm looking for something to contrast this.

What I've got is:

> This Radio Lab podcast talks about liars and self deception. It starts
>   off [platonically] enough, talking about everday lying and
>   pathological liars. The final part of it is where it gets
>   interesting – self deception.

Words I've consider are ***platonic***, ***neutral***. Platonic actually seems pretty reasonable here - it's usually used to contrast with romantic, but I think it can be used metaphorically here.

Comment: I would say "interesting but not relevant".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with **entertainingly**.

> **[entertainingly](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/entertainingly)** *adjective* affording entertainment; amusing; diverting:
>
> It starts off entertainingly enough, talking about everyday lying and pathological liars. The final part of it is where it gets interesting – self-deception.

It's straight-forward term that describes what I need, and its context ('entertainingly *enough*') suggests that it's *entertaining* but lacking something.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the word [***prosaically***,](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prosaically) meaning matter-of-fact; straightforward; lacking in imagination and spirit; dull.

> This Radio Lab podcast talks about liars and self deception. It starts off prosaically enough, talking about everyday lying and pathological liars. The final part of it is where it gets interesting – self deception.

Comment: I'm not looking for 'dull' though. As I said, it's _interesting_, but only as a factoid, not something relevant.

Comment: @dwjohnston: "Prosaic" needn't mean dull. Dull is but one legitimate use for the word. Prosaic  can also mean routine, ordinary, matter-of-fact, marginally interesting, or unimaginative, for starters. Don

Answer (score 1):

It starts off **idly** enough.... The final part of it is where it gets interesting....

(You had an *idle* interest in the first part of the program.)

Idle: [only before noun] without a good reason or real purpose

*It was only from idle curiosity that she opened the book.*

(macmillandictionary.com)

Answer (score 0):

The idiom ***have a keen interest in something*** is useful for your example.

> to have a strong interest in something; to be very interested in something.
>   <sub>[The Free Dictionary by Farlex](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+keen+interest+in)</sub>

If you apply *keenly* to the first part, it pairs with *interesting* in the second part to invoke the idiom to indicate the first part was not as relevant as the second part, but still of interest.

> It starts off *keenly* enough, talking about everday lying and pathological liars. The final part of it is where it gets *interesting* – self deception.

Answer (score -1):

Consider

> utopian -  excellent or ideal but impracticable; visionary; quixotic - extravagantly chivalrous or romantic; visionary, impractical, or impracticable.

Hope it helps